How does an L2 VPN actually work?
I don't think that I've understood how a L2 VPN actually works.
Whenever I ask someone about it they always answer that an L2 VPN works at layer 2 (frame) of the OSI model while an L3 vpn at the network layer (3).
Okay. I don't know much more now than I did before.
I mean, I understand the L3 one, packets need to be routed across the internet as usual, but what about L2?
How can your provider or any other router on the internet route a frame to its destination without the network layer?

It is exactly what I wanted to make sure about it. Thanks


How can your provider or any other router on the internet route a frame to its destination without the network layer?

First of all, VPNs are not necessarily meant to be routed over the Internet (nor used for accessing the Internet, for that matter). A major use case of VPNs is just to join together two local networks (site-to-site VPN) – a replacement for a leased line – and for such connections it could all remain within a single provider.
Also, broadly there are two meanings of "L2 VPN" depending on context:

Sometimes it's used to refer to VPNs that carry Ethernet frames over IP (i.e. the 'L2' refers only to the payload), with VXLAN or ZeroTier being some examples. Those function exactly like the typical "L3 VPN"; they still have an outer IP (often UDP/IP) header for routing, both internally to provider and externally across Internet.

Sometimes it's used to refer to VPNs that carry Ethernet frames "directly" over another local network, e.g. inside another Ethernet frame (i.e. the 'L2' refers primarily to the carrier). Those are not routed over the Internet – their purpose is to seamlessly join two locations that are connected to the same provider, but without having to dedicate a physical link.


(Although when you order a L2 VPN circuit from some carrier, you can't really tell the difference – it could be an Ethernet VLAN, or it could be based on MPLS, or it could just as well be carried as a VXLAN tunnel over IP.)
In the latter case, there are various ways to implement it. For example:

It could use plain "MAC-in-MAC" (e.g. 802.1ah), i.e. the Ethernet frames encapsulated in a second L2 header with a new destination MAC address, and the carrier's Ethernet switches forwarding in the regular way – in this case you could kind of think of Ethernet itself as being the outer network layer.

The VPN could be implemented as an MPLS network, with the Ethernet frames encapsulated in MPLS and forwarded between routers according to MPLS labels that define a specific path.



In general, I'd say do not think of the OSI model as anything more but guidelines for what its designers considered an 'ideal' network. The Internet was not built to the OSI model; indeed it was a competitor to the OSI-based networks. Likewise, Ethernet was not built as a "data link layer" for IP; it was originally built as a local network all by itself and only later adopted to carry other networks on top.

Maybe the kind or VPN I am interested to, and I'd like to understand better, is the Number 1 "Sometimes it's used to refer to VPNs that carry Ethernet frames over IP...", those deployed to connect distant sites at layer 2. So, if I got it right, the L2 frames travel encapsulated inside a packet routed as usual across the internet to reach their destinations.

There is really nothing special about that type. "Over IP" means that you still have exactly the same outer IP network layer as with 'regular' L3 VPNs.

A L2 VPN simulates layer 2, like an L3 VPN simulates layer 3. In either case, the packets at that layer are re-packaged into packets for whatever system the VPN is running on. Some of the layers will be duplicated.
For example, when I run an L2 OpenVPN over the Internet, OpenVPN creates a virtual Ethernet port in the operating system. When the OS sends L2 Ethernet frames through that port, the OpenVPN software puts them inside L3 Internet packets, and sends those through my real network port. The OpenVPN software on the other computer receives the Internet packet, takes the original Ethernet frame back out, and passes it to the OS which simulates receiving it on its virtual Ethernet port. Thus an Ethernet connection is simulated. From the OS point of view, Ethernet packets go out of a port, and arrive at another computer. Just like there was a real Ethernet cable between two real Ethernet ports.
When you look at the packet that goes through the Internet (say, in the middle of your ISP's network), it will have L2-L4 headers which direct it to the OpenVPN process on the receiving computer. Inside the L4 UDP header, it will have another set of L2-L7 headers, which are encrypted (not all VPNs encrypt them but OpenVPN does). There are two sets of L2-L4 headers which shouldn't get mixed up. The Internet only looks at the outer set, even when the inner set isn't encrypted.
L2 VPNs are somewhat less efficient than L3 because Ethernet uses broadcast traffic to discover other hosts and routers, which uses extra bandwidth, which is effectively free on fast local networks but not on slower networks like the internet. There's also the extra Ethernet header included in every packet which takes up space. Therefore L3 VPNs are usually preferred whenever possible.

Layer 2 VPN works like a network cable. Layer 3 and higher up are still there and available for routing and whatnot.
A Layer 3 IP tunnel cannot bridge Ethernet networks, because vital information is lost in transit: All non-IP traffic and also source and destination MAC addresses. Bridging could be emulated, to an extent, but not losslessly. A Layer 2 tunnel transports everything, acting essentially exactly like an Ethernet network cable between switches.
You should consider this categorization or designation as a “lower cutoff”.
Your local Ethernet network works, even across multiple switches and maybe routers, right? A Layer 2 tunnel is just like that.
